# Passar variável da pagina filha para a paǵina pai em jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlet, crud, servlet-3

Estou fazendo um simples `crud` em  java usando `jsp` e `servlets`.
E me deparei com a seguinte situação:

Tenho um `layout.jsp` que faz o include de uma outra página dinâmica, que nesse caso vai ser a `excluir.jsp`. O titulo da página  está definido dentro da `excluir.jsp` logo a página de  `layout.jsp` não enxerga o valor da minha variável `title`.

Pergunto: como fazer com que `layout.jsp` consiga pegar o valor da `title`.

**Obs:** Estou tentando ao máximo,  não colocar essas informações na `servlet`. Sim eu sei que se essa variável for definida na `servlet` o `layout .jsp` consegue pegar o valor.

> layout.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt"       prefix="c"   %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"       prefix="fmt" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml"       prefix="x"   %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql"       prefix="sql" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn"  %>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title><c:out value="${title}" /></title>
    <link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/css/theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
<c:import url="menu.jsp" />
<div class="container">
    <c:import url = "${page}" />
</div>
<script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

> excluir.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt"       prefix="c"   %>
<c:set var="title" scope="request" value="Excluir página"/>
<h1><c:out value="${title}" /></h1>
```

Comment: Tentou o usar o jsp:include? Nele você inclui páginas jsp e passa parâmetros para as filhas.

Comment: É ao contrário, tenho a página filha (é nela que tem o valor ) e a página pai que recebe a variável

Comment: Ahhhhh. Como tá no request, se usar um request.getParameter("title") na página pai não retorna o valor?

Comment: Não, vem em branco(`null`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare seu `c:import` como uma variável algum lugar antes de onde você está utilizando o atributo`title`. Exemplo:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt"       prefix="c"   %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"       prefix="fmt" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml"       prefix="x"   %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql"       prefix="sql" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn"  %>

<c:import var = "importedPage" url = "${page}" />   <%-- Aqui você declara seu import --%>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title><c:out value="${title}" /></title>
    <link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/css/theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
<c:import url="menu.jsp" />
<div class="container">
    ${importedPage}                                 <%-- Aqui você usa seu  import --%>
</div>
<script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Perfeito! muito obrigado.